# Partition of the interval

Tags: analysis

Write a non-uniform partition of the interval [0,√13] that has at
least 6 sub-intervals. Find the norm of your partition.

Comment: Welcome to math.stachexchange. Where is this problem come from? What have you tried for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_i= \frac{i}{10}$ for $i=0,1,...,7$ and $x_8= \sqrt{13}.$

Then

$$P=\{x_0,x_1,....,x_7,x_8\}$$

will do the job. It is your turn to compute the norm of $P$